# The Simplest pure Javascript code to build a looping slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I just want to learn the simplest way of javascript code to build a slideshow >
How does it understand a series of div`s or img`s and repeat them one by one ???
I know it is very simple for you but I am just in the starting point ! :D

Comment: `document.write('<input type="range">');`

Comment: My point is that the simplest slider is the one built into HTML5

Comment: Can u say the basic structure in javascript please?

Comment: @AlexK., looks like Mrx is asking about creating an image slideshow rather than the slider form control.

Comment: I mean image slider !! not input slider ! ;)

Comment: yes yes image slider :D sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, one way to create an automatically-looping image slider is to have JavaScript code run repeatedly (using `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`) to hide and show images on a page, one at a time.

You just need to have your image elements in an array that you can update at will.

Here's a basic example without any animation effects:

```js
(function() {
  var selectedIndex = -1;
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".slideshow img"),
    left = document.querySelector(".slideshow .left"),
    right = document.querySelector(".slideshow .right"),
    current = document.querySelector(".slideshow .current");
  var numSeconds = 2;
  var timeout;
  setIndex(0);
  left.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setIndex(selectedIndex - 1);
  });
  right.addEventListener("click", function() {
    setIndex(selectedIndex + 1);
  });

  function setIndex(i) {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
      imgs[selectedIndex].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (i >= imgs.length) {
      selectedIndex = 0;
    } else if (i < 0) {
      selectedIndex = 0;
    } else {
      selectedIndex = i;
    }
    imgs[selectedIndex].style.display = "inline-block";
    current.innerHTML = (selectedIndex + 1) + "/" + imgs.length;
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      setIndex(selectedIndex + 1)
    }, numSeconds * 1000);
  }
})();
```

```css
.slideshow img {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.slideshow .controls {
  max-width: 255px;
  text-align: center;
}
.slideshow .left {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slideshow .right {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/000000/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/ff0000/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/00ff00/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/0000ff/ffffff" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150/ffffff/000000" />
  <div class="controls"> <span class="left">&lt;&lt;</span>
    <span class="current"></span>
    <span class="right">&gt;&gt;</span>

  </div>
</div>
```

There are plenty of JavaScript libraries and jQuery extensions that you can use to get more functionality without having to write much code. I encourage you to explore what's already been developed to see the different implementations.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great help. actually I have sliders but I want to learn how they have been built in java script and your code makes it happen to me. Thank you so much.